# Getting outputs together into a dictionary

Tags: python

```
def firstone():
    x= 1
    print(x)


def firsttwo():
   y=1
   print(y)

   
**D={firstone,firsttwo}** ***#Problem is here***
```

What can be done to run the last line properly? Any ideas?

Comment: Also, both of your functions print to screen and return nothing. That's why you can't combine the result: There is none.

Comment: @576i because there is no firsttwo() and firstone() codes in the thread, the thing I want to understand how can I run them together in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `return` a value from your functions, if you just `print()`, their `return` would be `None`. If your goal is to create a `dict` when the output of `firstone()` is the `key` and the output of `firsttwo()` is the `value`:

**Code**:

```
def firstone():
    return 1


def firsttwo():
   return 1

d = {firstone(): firsttwo()}
```

**Output**:

```
{1: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure your functions actually return a value. Change it from printing to returning. Then call those function in the dictionary (notice the parentheses around the function name?).

```
def firstone():
    x= 1
    return x


def firsttwo():
   y=1
   return y

d = {"firstone":firstone(),"firsttwo":firsttwo()}
```